# Query alternative for NOT IN

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I have 2 big tables and would like to pull all fields on table1 if the 'Email Address' IS NOT exists in table2.

I have below but timeout.

```
SELECT 
  [Subscriber Key]
, [Email Address]
, [Create_Date_Sailthru]
, [Optin_Source]
, [First_Name]
, [Last_Open]
, [Last_Click]
, [Last_Pageview]
(and 20 other fields)
FROM [table1]
WHERE
    [Email Address] NOT IN (SELECT [Email Address] FROM [table2])
```

Comment: Is this a `marketing-cloud` question?

Comment: yes the execution will be on marketing cloud - query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My go-to for this scenario is something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.[Subscriber Key]
, t1.[Email Address]
, t1.[Create_Date_Sailthru]
, t1.[Optin_Source]
, t1.[First_Name]
, t1.[Last_Open]
, t1.[Last_Click]
, t1.[Last_Pageview]
FROM table1 t1
WHERE not exists (
  select top 1 *
  from table2 t2
  where t2.[email address] = t1.[email address] 
)
```

You could also do it less efficiently with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
  t1.[Subscriber Key]
, t1.[Email Address]
, t1.[Create_Date_Sailthru]
, t1.[Optin_Source]
, t1.[First_Name]
, t1.[Last_Open]
, t1.[Last_Click]
, t1.[Last_Pageview]
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.[email address] = t1.[email address] 
where t2.[emailaddress] is null
```

Comment: this one works for me..... duration: is 2:31 for using not exists and 2:33 for using left join. The total no of rows process is about 9M with 60 fields on table 1.

Comment: Just one further addition: right join is the same as left join performance wise.

Comment: that works too @JohannesSchapdick

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589870

Right column second row.

```
Select email 
from table1 as A 
Right join table2 as b on a.emailadress = b.emailaddress 
where a.emailaddress is null
```

Or

```
Select email 
from table2 as A 
Left join table1 as b on a.emailadress = b.emailaddress 
where b.emailaddress is null
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: You could do the same in a left join. Ofc you just have to switch tables in the query. And then you go with the first column second row of the picture.

Comment: Still cannot Believe this is a negative answer at all

Comment: this works too.